# Return id numbers if missing over a set of variables

Tags: r

If I have a large database, including an 'id' var, I want to list all variables of interest, and return back to myself a list of ids that are missing each particular variable.

```
#Fake Data:
set.seed(11100)
missdata<-data.frame(id<-1:1000,C1<-sample(c(1,NA),1000,replace=TRUE,prob=c(.8,.2)), C2<-sample(c(1,NA),1000,replace=TRUE,prob=c(.8,.2)))
names(missdata)<-c("id","v1","v2")


#One variable solution:
missdatatest<-subset(missdata, is.na(v1),select=id)
missdatatest[1:10,]
> missdatatest[1:10,]
[1]  5 30 44 47 48 49 57 65 68 74


#Looking to build a function...
FindMissings<-function(indata,varslist,printvar){
  printonevar<-function(var){
  missdatalist<-subset(indata, is.na(var),select=printvar)
  print(missdatalist)
}
lapply(vars,printonevar)
}


#Run function:
vars<-c("v1","v2")
FindMissings(missdata,vars,id)

#Error:
> FindMissings(missdata,vars,id)

 Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : undefined columns selected
```

Any help would be appreciated. I originally wrote a function to do this in SAS, and it works perfectly fine, but I'm trying to move a lot of my work into R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for such a function. Just use `lapply`:

```
> lapply(missdata[-1], function(x) which(is.na(x)))
$v1
  [1]   5  30  44  47  48  49  57  65  68  74  89 103 107 110 115 119 152 167
 [19] 175 176 194 197 199 202 204 212 215 223 231 232 233 239 245 280 281 293...
<<SNIP>>

$v2
  [1]   3   6  18  19  22  23  27  28  33  38  41  50  51  55  60  66  68  77
 [19]  81  84  86  96  97  99 109 116 117 134 139 141 143 146 148 153 165 168...
<<SNIP>>
```

If you specifically wanted to return the values from your "id" column (not just the position of the `NA` values), you can modify the statement to be:

```
lapply(missdata[-1], function(x) missdata$id[which(is.na(x))])
```

---

If your concern is how to use this approach for specific variables, it's pretty straightforward:

```
vars <- c("v1","v2")
lapply(missdata[vars], function(x) which(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: Well I'd like to output the list of ids for each variable into a separate document "eventually", with a title specific to that variable. That is the stuff I know how to do once I get separate lists for each through some iterative process. I'm not sure how I'd do it through the process you've shown. 

And it seems that this does ALL variables. I will want to only do some variables IRL.

Comment: @user2438475: You can easily access list items by their positions or names. If you had stored the output of the above as "out", getting the result for "v1" would be done with `out[[1]]` or `out[["v1"]]`.